# Updating large quantities of data in a production database

Tags: mysql, import

I have a large quantity of data in a production database that I want to update with batches of data  while the data in the table is still available for end user use. The updates could be insertion of new rows or updates of existing rows. The specific table is approximately 50M rows, and the updates will be between 100k - 1M rows per "batch". What I would like to do is insert replace with a low priority.. In other words, I want the database to kind of slowly do the batch import without impacting performance of other queries that are occurring concurrently to the same disk spindles. To complicate this, the update data is heavily indexed. 8 b-tree indexes across multiple columns to facilitate various lookup that adds quite a bit of overhead to the import.

I've thought about batching the inserts down into 1-2k record blocks, then having the external script that loads the data just pause for a couple seconds between each insert, but that's really kind of hokey IMHO. Plus, during a 1M record batch, I really don't want to add 500-1000 2second pauses to add 20-40 minutes of extra load time if its not needed. Anyone have ideas on a better way to do this?

Comment: wait for low activity period, or as you suggest, make the batches much smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've dealt with a similar scenario using InnoDB and hundreds of millions of rows. Batching with a throttling mechanism is the way to go if you want to minimize risk to end users. I'd experiment with different pause times and see what works for you. With small batches you have the benefit that you can adjust accordingly. You might find that you don't need any pause if you run this all sequentially. If your end users are using more connections then they'll naturally get more resources.

If you're using MyISAM there's a LOW_PRIORITY option for [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html). If you're using InnoDB with replication be sure to check that it's not getting too far behind because of the extra load. Apparently it runs in a single thread and that turned out to be the bottleneck for us. Consequently we programmed our throttling mechanism to just check how far behind replication was and pause as needed.

Answer (score 3):

An [INSERT DELAYED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-delayed.html) might be what you need. From the linked documentation:

> Each time that [`delayed_insert_limit`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_delayed_insert_limit) rows are written, the handler checks whether any [SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) statements are still pending. If so, it permits these to execute before continuing.

Comment: I've been looking at this, but the documentation says it will ignore the delayed if there is an on duplicate key update.

Comment: There's also a [REPLACE DELAYED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html). Unfortunately it is not explained how DELAYED works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html  What I would do is write a script that will execute your batch updates when MySQL is showing Threads_running or Connections under a certain number.  Hopefully you have some sort of test server where you can determine what a good number threshold might be for either of those server variables.  There are plenty of other of server status variables to look at in there also.  Maybe control the executions by the Innodb_data_pending_writes number?  Let us know what works for you, its an interesting question!